# Why minimal difference in density curves for P=0.05 and P=0.01

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have 2 dataframes (df1 and df2), each having 2 columns (`acol` and `bcol`). The P values of difference between `acol` and `bcol` in 2 dataframes are 0.05 and 0.01, respectively. Following are the description of data and P values:

```
======================= df1 =======================
         acol    bcol
count 137.000 137.000
mean    9.924  10.165
std     1.079   0.950
min     7.677   8.332
25%     9.229   9.523
50%     9.993   9.976
75%    10.527  10.853
max    12.563  12.478
P = 0.05046
======================= df2 =======================
         acol    bcol
count 150.000 150.000
mean    9.899  10.202
std     1.068   0.942
min     7.677   8.332
25%     9.220   9.555
50%     9.987  10.046
75%    10.465  10.870
max    12.563  12.478
P = 0.00966
```

I expected prominent difference between density curves of `acol` vs `bcol` in two dataframes. However, I got following plots:

[image]

To my surprise, these are nearly identical (they can go for a "Spot the differences" quiz!)

Is there some error in above data or calculations? Otherwise, why is there minimal difference between density plots of data with P=0.05 and P=0.01, which would normally be described as "borderline different" vs "clearly different", respectively?

Comment: Your slightly larger sample size could be driving the difference.

Comment: You should not be giving interpretations like you gave at the end of your question for p values.  Those interpretations are wrong

Comment: How should we interpret P values of 0.05 and 0.01?